# Absolute element inside relative (with % set height) overlaps outside parent

Tags: html, css

Basically I've got a wrapper to which I've added the (relevant) css properties:

`height: 100%; float: left; margin: 10px 10px; position: relative;`

with a nested div styled as

`display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;`

with `display: block;` taking effect on hover of the parent, targeting the nested div.

The issue is that when it's hovered, the nested div overlaps the parent by about 4-5px. I can completely eliminate this issue by stating a set height on the parent element, but I would rather **keep the height at 100%** if possible!

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Trblestrife/Y9ztq/1/

**EDIT** If you know what's wrong but can't be bothered answering give me a hint and I'll do more research. I'm asking here because I've run out of ideas as to where to look

Thanks very much

Comment: Make your img `display:block` and it should fix your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably that images, because they are `inline` elements, can add trailing whitespace at the bottom. Generally a fix is to give their parent element a line-height of nothing:

```
.featured-projectwrap{

  line-height:0;

}
```

But this would mean any text nested would not be visible, so compensate by re-promoting the line-height at the caption level:

```
.caption{

  line-height:1;

}
```

Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9ztq/2/) with the changes...